# Drone YAML if condition is not working

Tags: build, continuous-integration, yaml, drone.io

I have below conditional logic in the Drone YAML, but I saw that the control is not going inside that, even though drone branch is "develop". How to fix this, did I do anything wrong?

```
commands:
      - "./gradlew clean build"
      - echo "${DRONE_BRANCH}"
      - echo "${DRONE_BRANCH}" = "develop"
      - >
        if [ "${DRONE_BRANCH}" = "develop" ]; then
            export CLOUD_USER_KEY=$STAGE_CLOUD_USER_KEY
            export HOST_NAME="11.22.111.111"
        fi
      - >
        if [ "${DRONE_BRANCH}" = "master" ]; then
            export CLOUD_USER_KEY=$PROD_CLOUD_USER_KEY
            export HOST_NAME="11.22.111.112"
        fi

      - echo "CLOUD_USER_KEY "${CLOUD_USER_KEY}
      - echo "HOST NAME "${HOST_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

`>` is the YAML indicator for a *folded* block scalar. Line folding in YAML means that a line break between two non-empty consecutive lines is changed into a space. This is not what you want when writing bash commands into YAML!

For example, this simple folded block scalar (using only parts of your original YAML file):

```
- >
  export CLOUD_USER_KEY=$STAGE_CLOUD_USER_KEY
  export HOST_NAME="11.22.111.111"
```

will be parsed as:

```
- "export CLOUD_USER_KEY=$STAGE_CLOUD_USER_KEY export HOST_NAME=\"11.22.111.111\"\n"
```

Which won't work. Use a *literal* block scalar instead which preserves line endings:

```
- |
  export CLOUD_USER_KEY=$STAGE_CLOUD_USER_KEY
  export HOST_NAME="11.22.111.111"
```

Comment: *still not working* is never a valid description of a problem. Since you have debug output in your YAML, show the actual output.